# 'str' object has no attribute 'values' - Object Does Not Appear to be String

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing, chunking

I am attempting to multiprocess a pandas `read_sq()` import with chunking. The end goal is to find the distance between two lats/lons. Since I am working in a Jupyter Notebook, the functions for `multiprocessing` need to be in a separate file. That file looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
import numpy as np

engine = create_engine('engine-path')

data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from SCHEMA.TABLE", engine)  

def cartesian_product_simplified(left, right):
    la, lb = len(left), len(right)
    ia2, ib2 = np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ogrid[:la,:lb])
    return pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([left.values[ia2.ravel()], right.values[ib2.ravel()]]))

def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    m = 3956.269 * c
    return m

def getDistance(chunk):
    df = cartesian_product_simplified(chunk, data)
    df = df.rename(columns={1:'lat1',2:'lon1',6:'lat2',7:'lon2'})
    df = df.astype({"lat1": float,"lon1": float,"lat2": float,"lon2": float})
    m = haversine_np(df['lon1'],df['lat1'],df['lon2'],df['lat2'])
    dist = pd.DataFrame(m.values)
    result = df.join(dist)
    result = result.rename(columns={0:'dist'})
    result = result[result['dist']<=3]
    return result
```

The main notebook looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from dist_func import getDistance

from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global result
    p = Pool(20)
    for chunk in pd.read_sql("select top 10 * from SCHEMA.SecondTable", engine, chunksize=1):
        result = p.map(getDistance, chunk)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

This results in this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\filepath\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\filepath\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\filepath\dist_func.py", line 30, in getDistance
    df = cartesian_product_simplified(chunk, vendor_geo)
  File "C:\Users\filepath\dist_func.py", line 18, in cartesian_product_simplified
    return pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([left.values[ia2.ravel()], right.values[ib2.ravel()]]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

This is pointing to the `cartesian_product_simplified` function that feeds into the `getDistance` function. However, when I remove multiprocessing and simply chunk through the `read_sql()` query like this...

```
for chunk in pd.read_sql("select top 100 * from SCHEMA.SecondTable", engine, chunksize=10):
    df = cartesian_product_simplified(chunk, data)
    df = df.astype({"lat1": float,"lon1": float,"lat2": float,"lon2": float})
    df = df.astype({"lat1": float,"lon1": float,"lat2": float,"lon2": float})
    m = haversine_np(df['lon1'],df['lat1'],df['lon2'],df['lat2'])
    dist = pd.DataFrame(m.values)
    result = df.join(dist)
    result = result.rename(columns={0:'dist'})
    result = result[result['dist']<=3]
    df_list.append(result)
```

...no such error is thrown. This is with using the exact same functions. Why is this error occurring when it seems like the function is being fed two DataFrames, and it works without multiprocessing involved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause, but choosing a smaller number of partitions fixed this same problem for me on my own dataset. So, the error may be directly or indirectly related to the number of partitions you are selecting or the ratio of partitions to rows in your dataset. For larger datasets, I did not have this problem.